# strong induction factoring question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I seen an example from my book and the factoring didn't make any sense  can someone help me understand the factoring that they used?

suppose that $e_0, e_1, e_2... $ is a sequence defined as follows:

$e_0 =12 $,  $e_1 =29 $

$e_k = 5e_{k-1}-6e_{k-2}$, for all integers $k \ge2$

Prove that $e_n=5*3^n+7*2^n$ ,for all integers  $k \ge0$

Skip.. to inductive hypothesis

$5(5*3^k+7*2^k)-6(5*3^{k-1}+7*2^{k-1})$

$25*3^k+35*2^k-30*3^{k-1}-42*2^{k-1}$

$25*3^k+35*2^k-10*3*3^{k-1}-21*2*2^{k-1}$

$25*3^k+35*2^k-10*3^{k}-21*2^{k}$    (i don't get this line where did the 2k, where it says $35*2^k$  )

$(25-10)*3^k+(35-21)*2^k$

$15*3^k+14*2^k$

$5*3*3^k+7*2*2^k$

$5*3^{k+1}+7*2^{k+1}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's being asked, but I can explain what's going on with each line.

$25*3^k + 35 * 2^k - 30 * 3^{k-1} - 42 * 2^{k-1}$ (Distribution of coefficients)

$25*3^k + 35 * 2^k - 10 * 3 * 3^{k-1} - 21 * 2 * 2^{k-1}$ (Breaking down the coefficients of the last two terms, so that we can increase the exponential segments of the terms)

$25*3^k + 35 * 2^k - 10 * 3^k - 21 * 2^k$ (The aforementioned increasing of exponents)

I'm going to add a few lines to show more clearly what's going on:

$25*3^k - 10 * 3^k + 35 * 2^k - 21 * 2^k$ (Reorganizing the terms)

$(25*3^k - 10 * 3^k) + (35 * 2^k - 21 * 2^k)$ (Collecting like exponential terms into parentheses)

$3^k(25-10) + 2^k(35-21)$ (Extracting like exponents, via the distribution property)

$15*3^k + 14*2^k$ (Simplifying the operations in the parentheses)

And the rest is straightforward. Hope this helps!